# RewriteRule in htaccess doesn`t work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I`ve got this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/partner/partnername$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newpartner.domain.de [L,R=301]
```

But when I go to "www.domain.com/partner/partnername" it doesn`t redirect.
Can you guys help me with that?

RewriteEngine is On.

Comment: see the first RewriteCond .de/.com

Comment: I´ve got both tld. ".de" and ".com" both are not working.

Comment: I'd remove the REQUEST_URI's end-line anchor `$`, since not sure about the last slash.

Comment: Its works now, I dont know realy why but it works. :D

Comment: The [`DirectorySlash `](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) is on by default.